# How do i initialize an array in a fucntion whose length is given by a formal parameter in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

for example,

```
int func(int len){
int arr[len];
}
```

this doesn't compile. with the error

> expression did not evaluate to a constant.

so, how can i initialize an array in such a way?

Comment: Not in standard C++. You'd have to use a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2):

In fact the function deals with a variable length array. The C++ Standard does not allow to use variable length arrays though some compilers have their own language extensions that support variable length arrays.

So in any case you have to allocate the array dynamically/. Either you can do this using the operator new as it is shown in the demonstrative program below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <numeric>

void func( size_t n )
{
    std::unique_ptr<int[]>a( new ( std::nothrow ) int[n] );

    if ( a )
    {
        std::iota( a.get(), a.get() + n, 0 );

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) std::cout << a[i] << ' ';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main() 
{
    func( 10 );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Or you can use the standard container std::vector that itself allocates dynamically memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>

void func( size_t n )
{
    std::vector<int> v( n );

    std::iota( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ), 0 );

    for ( const auto &item : v ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
    func( 10 );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above.

Comment: I'd mention `std::unique_ptr<int[]>a = std::make_unique<int[]>(n);` to stay away from `new[]` completely, but you got my vote.

Answer (score 1):

Because your variable given could be dynamic I would use a vector:

```
#include <vector>

int func(const int len){
std::vector<int> arr(len);
}
```

if you want to avoid std::vector, you would use `const` (not required, but in the control structure you would not change the value):

```
int func(const int len){
  int arr[len];
}
```

It least my compiler g++ 9.2 accepts that, but only if the feature Variable Length Array (VLA) is enabled. That is not part of the C++ standard though.

Comment: You should have left the second part out. It'll only work with `constexpr` arguments.

Comment: @Dr.-Ing. Gerhard Stein This int func(const int len){
  int arr[len];
} is not a valid standard C++ code.

Comment: To get your `g++` compiler to not let `VLA`:s through, use `-pedantic-errors` when compiling. It should report: `error: ISO C++ forbids variable length array 'arr' [-Wvla]` for the second part of your answer. Just remove that.

Comment: @Dr.-Ing.GerhardStein You're welcome - but if `VLA`:s would be supported, then OP:s code would work as-is. There's no need for `const`.

Answer (score -1):

Static arrays like arr[] must have known length at compile time. You need to dynamically allocate, so use:
Int* arr = new int[len];

Comment: Yes, but remember to also deallocate with ```delete []``` when you have finished.

Comment: @TedLyngmo why not?

Comment: @user12962917 There are tons of examples why not here on SO. You don't even mention the importance of making sure that every `new[]` has exactly one `delete[]`. Making sure that is the case is not something for beginners. Look at the answer by @Kushagra for yet another example why not.

Comment: `vector<T>` was made for this. Please stop reinventing your own memory management hacks.

Answer (score -3):

Basically, u need to allocate the array dynamically, therefore u can use new or malloc, in this case,

```
int fun(int len)
{
int *ar; 
ar=new int [len];
for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
{
cin>>ar[i];
}
}
```

Now its all upto you what you want from your code now . 
remmber if u are using malloc include  header file in c or c++

Comment: ... and there you have a leak.

Comment: That's a syntax error. Better stick to vector if you don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: It's still not syntactically correct - but even if it was, why suggest this over a `std::vector`?

Comment: sorry for being new to stack overflow and doing so many mistakes on my first answer, I think I have correct most the segment in my code. Thanks for the feedback sir

Comment: it's still not correct - you delete arrays with `delete[]`.

Comment: Ok , I got your point Now , i think so it wouldn't be a problem now after removing the delete statement , further if u want to clear the memory created then if function is declared in a class a destructor could be declared and passed the delete/free statement to clear memory, right ?

Comment: That would not be possible because `ar` is a local variable. The moment the function returns, you have a memory leak - unless you `delete[]` it. Also, `free` is not an option for memory allocated with `new` or `new[]` as `free` does not call destructors. All this uncertainty is a very good reason to use `std::vector` instead.